# Javascript - Condition always returns 0 on Android

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch

I just experienced the weirdest thing. I'm developing my app with sencha, when the app loads (`body onload="doStuff()"`) I do a test to detect the device's orientation, where I do this :

```
var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
var orientation = bodyHeight > bodyWidth;
```

`alert(orientation) :`

- On desktop : it shows `true`
- On Android : it shows `0` which means false, and that always happens regardless of the device's orientation

Can somebody please explain ?!

EDIT: `bodyHeight` and `bodyWidth` both have correct values. Even `alert(bodyHeight > bodyWidth)` shows true

Comment: So alert(bodyHeight>bodyWidth) shows true, but alert(orientation) shows 0 (false)? Weird..

Comment: You posted this with the sencha-touch keyword. So why not use this: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.device.Orientation  It does not answer your problem, but it works.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what the problem was : `orientation` is a **keyword** in Android Browsers. Changing the variable name solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In controls, catch the orientation change event like below:

```
viewport: {
   //capture the orientation change event
   orientationchange: 'onOrientationchange'
 }

onOrientationchange: function(viewport, orientation) {
    dostuff() // based on orientation
}
```

Apart from this, what you were trying, you should have tried `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`

A practical JavaScript solution (covering all browsers):

```
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;
```